# Biblatex: how to "fullcite" the first occurences and "cite" the others

Tags: biblatex

I am using `xelatex` and `biblatex` (backend `biber`), and I would like the `\cite` command to act as `\fullcite` whenever a reference is cited the first time. For instance, say my document is as follows:

```
This is the first time I cite \cite{book1},
and this is the second time I cite \cite{book1}.
This is the first time I cite \cite{book2}.
```

Then I would like it to be compiled as

```
This is the first time I cite \fullcite{book1},
and this is the second time I cite \cite{book1}.
This is the first time I cite \fullcite{book2}.
```

Possibly, I would prefer defining a new command, e.g. `\mycite`, so that I can still use the original `\cite`.

Besides, how to tell `\fullcite` which fields to print, without interfering with how the references in the bibliography are shown?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can use the preamble option:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,…,citestyle=verbose,…]{biblatex}
```

It does exactly what you want; `verbose`can be replaced by one of the derived styles:

`verbose-ibid`, `verbose-note`, `verbose-inote`, `verbose-trad1`, `verbose-trad2`, `verbose-trad3`,

as defined in §3.3.1 of the doc.

For the second question, probably you should define some \myfullcite command. I can say no more, as you do not give any details.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! But from the second citation on, the author and the title is printed, instead of the corresponding number as it is in the bibliography (e.g. [12], as it would be without the `citestyle=verbose` option). Besides, package `hyperref` creates a link that links to the first citation, rather than to the bibliography. Is there a way to correct these issues?

Comment: When I use fullcite it only prints first-collaborator and collaborators.  How can I get the full name of all of them?